# How can I load script and style in specific page in the back-end?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am new in WordPress so I am building my first theme with theme options I am facing the problem in my theme options pages that I have made in admin. I have two different styles for my theme options in admin area when I enqueue scripts for admin the problem are as follows:

1. When I enqueue the scripts the script loaded on all the admin pages I just want it to load it on my theme options page
2. As I mentioned above that I have two different styles according to two different pages of theme options. How can I load the style accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So simple I will explain it step by step:

1. First, use the $hook variable that is WordPress default like this:

   ```
   function the_themescripts($hook) {
       echo $hook;
   }
   add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'dr_theme_options_style_scripts' );
   ```
2. Now go to custom page in your admin WP Dashboard and at the top you will see something like 
   `toplevel_page_your_theme_page_slug` if it does not visible to you try to inspect element and see after  tag copy that and use like this.
3. Use of `$hook` variable. Use it inside the if else loop

   ```
   function the_themescripts($hook) {
     echo $hook;

     if ($hook == 'toplevel_page_your_page_slug') :
         // enqueue your script/styles here for your first page    
     endif;

     if ($hook == 'your second page slug' ) :
         // enqueue your script/styles here for your first page
     endif
   }
   add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'the_themescripts' );
   ```

Hope this explanation helps:)

Answer (score 2):

To detect the current page in the admin panel, you can use a global variable named `$pagenow`. Take a look at this example:

```
function my_admin_enqueue() {
    global $pagenow;
    // Get the current page
    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {
        $current_page = $_GET['page'];
    } else {
        $current_page = '';
    }
    // Check both current page base and slug
    if( ( $pagenow == 'themes.php' ) && ( $current_page == 'my-theme-settings' ) ) {
        // Now enqueue your script and styles here
    }
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_admin_enqueue');
```